# How can I run a simple parallel array assignment operation in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I have to solve a differential equations system many times, iterating over a parameter. For this, I run a loop over a list of the parameter, and store the solution (evaluated at an array of time values) for each parameter. So I have a 2D array in which I store solutions (each row is for a value of the parameter).

Now, since any iteration has nothing to do with another one, I thought of doing this in parallel.

Here is my code:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using SharedArrays
using DelimitedFiles
using Distributed

function tf(x,w)
    return x*sin(w*x)
end

function sys!(dv,v,w,t)
    dv[1] = w*v[1]
    dv[2] = tf(v[1],w)
end

times = LinRange(0.1,2,25)

params = LinRange(0.1,1.2,100)

sols = SharedArray{Float64,2}((length(times),length(params)))

@distributed for i=1:length(params)
    println(i)
    init_val = [1.0,1.0]
    tspan = (0.0,2.0)
    prob = ODEProblem(sys!,init_val,tspan,params[i])
    sol = solve(prob)
    sols[:,i] .= sol(times)[2,:]
end

writedlm("output.txt",sols)
```

Now, when I run this without the @distributed prefixed to the loop, this runs perfectly.

When I run this code, however, the println statement does not work, and although the file "output.txt" is stored, it is full of zeros.

I'm running this code from the command line this way

```
julia -p 4 trycode.jl
```

This shows no output and just works for a minute and does nothing, although the file "output.txt" is stored. It's as if the loop is never entered.

I would really appreciate some help on how to set up this simple parallel loop.

Comment: What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: @OscarSmith 1.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Bill says there's two main ways to think about parallelism in Julia: the threaded model, which was introduced in Julia 1.3 and does shared memory parallelism via the `Threads.@threads` macro, and distributed processing using the `Distributed.@distributed` macro, which parallelizes across different Julia processes.

Threads is definitely closer to an "automagic" parallelism speed-up with minimal or no re-write of code and often a great option, although one has to take care to ensure that whatever operation one is running is threadsafe, so do always check that results come out the same.

As your question was about `@distributed` parallelism originally, let me answer that as well. If you do `@distributed` parallelism, the simplest mental model (I believe) to think about what's going on is to imagine you're running your code in entirely seperate Julia REPLs.

Here's a version of your code adapted to the `@distributed` model:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)

using SharedArrays
using DelimitedFiles

@everywhere begin 
    using DifferentialEquations

    tf(x,w) = x*sin(w*x)

    function sys!(dv,v,w,t)
        dv[1] = w*v[1]
        dv[2] = tf(v[1],w)
    end

    times = LinRange(0.1,2,25)
    params = LinRange(0.1,1.2,100)
end

sols = SharedArray{Float64,2}((length(times),length(params)))

@sync @distributed for i=1:length(params)
    println(i)
    init_val = [1.0,1.0]
    tspan = (0.0,2.0)
    prob = ODEProblem(sys!,init_val,tspan,params[i])
    sol = solve(prob)
    sols[:,i] .= sol(times)[2,:]
end

sols
```

What has changed?

- I added `addprocs(2)` at the start of the script. This isn't necessary if you start Julia with `p -2` (or whatever number of processes you want) as you do it, but I often find it easier to reason about the code when it explicitly sets up the parallel environment in the code directly. Note that this isn't currently possible for threads, i.e. you need to set your `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable before starting Julia and can't change the number of threads once you're up and running.
- I then moved bits of the code into a `@everywhere begin ... end` block. This essentially runs the operations enclosed in the block on all processes at the same time. Going back to the mental model of running separate Julia instances, you have to look at what's in your `@distributed` loop and make sure that all functions and variables are actually defined on all processes. So e.g. to ensure that every process knows what `ODEProblem` is, you need to do `using DifferentialEquations` on all of them.
- Finally, I added `@sync` to the distributed loop. This is referenced in the docs for the [`@distributed`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.@distributed). Running `@distributed` macro with `for` loop spawns an asynchronous green thread (`Task`) handle for the distributed execution and moves forward to the next line. Since you want to wait until the execution actually get done the synchronization `@sync` is required. The issue with your original code is that without waiting for the green thread to complete (synchronizing), it will swallow errors and just return immediately, which is why your `sol` array is empty. You can see this if you run your original code, and only add the `@sync` - you will then get a `TaskFailedException: on worker 2 - UndefVarError: #sys! not defined` which tells you that your worker processes don't know about the functions you defined on the master process. In practice you will almost always want `@sync` execution, unless you you plan to run many such distributed loops in parallel. You also do not need the `@sync` keyword where you use aggregator function in the distributed loop (the `@distributed (func) for i in 1:1000` form of the loop)

Now what's the best solution here? The answer is I don't know. `@threads` is a great option to quickly parallelize thread-safe operation without rewriting the code, and is still actively being developed and improved so likely to become even better in future. There is also [`pmap`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.pmap) in the Distributed standard library which gives you additional options, but this answer is long enough as it is! In my personal experience, nothing replaces (1) thinking about your problem and (2) benchmarking execution. Things you want to think about are the runtime of your problem (both total and for every individual operation that you want to distribute) and message passing/memory access requirements.

The upside is that while you might have to spend a bit of effort thinking about things, Julia has a bunch of great options to make the most out of every hardware situation from a crappy old laptop with two cores (like the one I'm typing this from) to multi-node super high performance clusters (which has made Julia one of the very few programming language to [achieve petaflop performance](https://www.hpcwire.com/off-the-wire/julia-joins-petaflop-club/) - although to be fair this is a little more tricky then my or Bill's answer :))

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Your answer was really helpful in understanding what's happening here.

I have a followup question here: for my actual problem, I know that the last 50 values of the parameter have a high computation time, and they are the ones that hold the code up. Is there a way to elegantly specify how exactly the processes divide the elements of the loop among themselves? i.e., For 4 processes, process 1 should get i=1,5,9... and so on.

This way, the load is equally distributed among the 4 processes. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: So I'm not exactly sure, but I think `@sync @distributed` does this already - i.e. any processor gets allocated the next task whenever they're done, and if one takes longer than another one should get a few. Try this: `using Distributed; addprocs(2); @sync @distributed for s in [1,2,3,4,10,1,1,1]; println("Waiting for $s seconds"); sleep(s); end` - this should give you the idea. Also look at the `pmap` docs, it takes a `batch_size` argument that gives you more control over how to split up computations I think.

Comment: Unfortunately `@distributed` allocates all tasks with exactly the same number of computations. Hence if you have unbalanced computation times this might not be good way to go (unless you have plenty of jobs and you have good chance it balances out).

Comment: Regarding what is better `Thread` or `@distributed` - in practice Julia threads scale badly when there are too many of them. Hence if you are utilizing 2 or 4 cores you are OK with both threads and `@distributed`, if this is 64 cores you definitely want `@distributed`

Answer (score 3):

Can you benefit from threaded for instead for @distributed for? This works (Julia 1.4):

```
using DifferentialEquations
using SharedArrays
using DelimitedFiles
using Distributed

function tf(x,w)
    return x*sin(w*x)
end

function sys!(dv,v,w,t)
    dv[1] = w*v[1]
    dv[2] = tf(v[1],w)
end

times = LinRange(0.1,2,25)

params = LinRange(0.1,1.2,100)

sols = SharedArray{Float64,2}((length(times),length(params)))

@Threads.threads for i=1:length(params)
    println(i)
    init_val = [1.0,1.0]
    tspan = (0.0,2.0)
    prob = ODEProblem(sys!,init_val,tspan,params[i])
    sol = solve(prob)
    sols[:,i] .= sol(times)[2,:]
end

writedlm("output.txt",sols)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I guess I have a follow-up question. Is there a way to tell the threads how to distribute the loop? As I understand, this splits the loop into equal parts, but in my actual problem, large parameter values (all stored late in the array) take more time, so I'd like the distribution to be split evenly, i.e. with 4 processes, the first thread should get elements {1,5,9} and so on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Also, when I run this from the command line, it uses only one thread, despite me adding "addprocs(4)" to the code and using julia -p 4 while executing.

Comment: You may need to set the number of threads for the CPU with setting JULIA_NUM_THREADS in the environment before running Julia.

Comment: @hg153 What you are asking for is commonly called "load balancing" and, as you noted, `Threads.@threads` doesn't do it. Instead of `Threads.@threads`, you can use `Threads.@spawn` individually within the loop to spawn your calculations on different threads. This will balance the load.