# Parallel assignment operations with nested loops in Julia 1.5

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, julia, nested-loops

This is a closely related to the following post, answered very well by Przemyslaw Szufel.

[How can I run a simple parallel array assignment operation in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61399925/how-can-i-run-a-simple-parallel-array-assignment-operation-in-julia/61402966#61402966)

Given that I have a 40-core machine, I decided to follow Przemyslaw's advice and go with @distributed, rather than Threads, to perform the array assignment operations. This sped things up quite nicely.

My algorithm's only slight difference with the above user's situation is that I have **nested** loops. Of course, I could always vectorize the array I'm performing the assignment operation on, but that would complicate my code. Should I simply include @sync @distributed before the outermost loop, and leave it at that? Or would I need to put additional macros before the (two, in my case) inner loops to maximize the benefits of parallelization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of distributed loops you normally want to parallelize only the outermost loop. Why? Because distributed the workload takes a significant amount of time.

However there are scenarios where you might want to search for different parallelization strategies.

Let us consider a scenario with unbalanced execution time. `@distributed` takes a naive approach equally splitting the loop between the workers. Suppose you have a loop such as:

```
for i in 1:100
    for j in 1:i
       ## do some heavy-lifting
    end
end
```

Putting `@distributed` before the outer loop will be very inefficient because all parallel executions is going to wait for the last chunk where all the longest values of `j` will be processed. This is a typical loop where the value of parallelization is going to be almost non-existent.
In situation like this there are usually to approaches:

- lazy approach: parallelize over the inner loop. This will be good where `i` takes values orders of magnitude greater than the number of cores
- efficient approach. Create a proxy variable  `k in 1:(100*(100+1)/2)`, distribute over it and then calculate corresponding values of `i` and `j`

Finally, if the job times are heavily unbalanced and the approach above does not work you need to use some job polling mechanism. One way to go could be to use `asyncmap` to spawn remote tasks another way to go would be use external tools - I usually use simple some `bash` scripts for that - I published my approach to using bash to parallelize jobs on GitHub: https://github.com/pszufe/KissCluster

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you Przemyslaw. Just a very clear explanation. I think the inner loop's nodes take about the same amount of time, but in case that's not true, I will try the efficient approach, or load balance polling, as you suggested. If you have any good references or books on parallel processing (not necessarily Julia-specific) to share, I'd love to hear about them!

Comment: You could try to search for videos from JuliaCon by Matt Bauman they are good tutorials. I am also making Julia distributed computing workshops at different places from time to time. It would be also a good idea to read all posts on SO having tags `julia` and `parallel-processing` or `julia` and `distributed`. I remember writing here several useful and production-ready recipes that you can use for your workloads.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendations. I will check them out, and I'll look out for your workshops, also!